# C Compiler not throwing error when no type is specified

Tags: c, gcc, implicit-int

Why this below program not throwing an error:

```
dfljshfksdhfl;
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
        return 0;
}
```

`gcc` would just throw a warning:

> test.c:1:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]

Answer (score 7):

This is because even though [implicit int is no longer part of the C standard since C99](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26488502/1708801) some compilers still support it, mainly to prevent breaking a lot of old code. So this line:

```
dfljshfksdhfl;
```

ends up being equivalent to:

```
int dfljshfksdhfl;
```

`clang` gives us a much more informative warning by default:

```
warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
dfljshfksdhfl;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

We can use the [-pedantic-errors](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) flag to turn this into an error, although oddly enough this does not work for `clang` and so we have to resort to `-Werror` and turn all warnings into errors, which is actually a good habit to get into. As remyabel points out for `clang` we can also use `-Werror=implicit-int`.

Comment: Oddly enough, `-Werror=implicit-int` works for Clang but not GCC, while `-pedantic-errors` works for GCC but not Clang.

Answer (score 1):

I've already answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189962/implicit-int-in-c-language/26190042#26190042) (actually I'm pretty sure it's a duplicate, but whatever) and the answer is found in the C99 rationale.

> A new feature of C99:
>
> In C89, all type specifiers could be omitted from the declaration
>   specifiers in a declaration. In such a case int was implied. The
>   Committee decided that the inherent danger of this feature outweighed
>   its convenience, and so it was removed. The effect is to guarantee the
>   production of a diagnostic that will catch an additional category of
>   programming errors. After issuing the diagnostic, **an implementation
>   may choose to assume an implicit int and continue to translate the
>   program in order to support existing source code that exploits this
>   feature.**

@Shafik's answers tells you one way to turn the warning into an error (for Clang). If you consider `-Werror` to be too strict, you can turn that one warning into an error with `-Werror=implicit-int`. In GCC, it appears that `-pedantic-errors` is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, gcc is not a conforming C compiler by default. It implements a dialect of C89/C90 with GNU extensions.

You can use `-std=cNN -pedantic` (where `NN` can be `90`, `99`, or `11`) to cause it to (attempt to) conform to a specified version of the ISO C standard. C90 permitted implicit `int`; it was dropped in C99.

But C compilers are not actually *required* to generate fatal error messages (except for a `#error` directive). The standard's requirement ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 5.1.1.3p1) is:

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic
>   message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a
>   preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a
>   violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is
>   also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined.
>   Diagnostic messages need not be produced in other circumstances.

A non-fatal warning qualifies as a "diagnostic message". A conforming C compiler can print a warning for any error -- even a syntax error -- and then continue to successfully compiler the source file. (This is how some compiler-specific language extensions may be supported.)

Personally, I find gcc to be overly lax about certain errors; in my opinion, a missing `int` *should* be treated as a fatal error. But that's just my preference, not a requirement imposed by the standard.

The lesson here is that you should not assume that mere warnings are harmless. Ideally, compiling your code should produce no diagnostics *at all*. Cases where it's ok to ignore warnings are rare (but they do exist, since compilers are free to warn about perfectly valid code).