# Warning] data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]

Tags: c, class, storage, definition

For college I need to create a basic desk calculator using the template provided. I've managed to get most of it done but there is this error message on line 9 (`iScreenSetup();`:

> " [Warning] data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]"

Any tips?

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"



/* Prototypes */
iScreenSetup();
iDataCapture();
iProcessData();
iReport();
iExit();

/* Declare and initialise global variables */
float fNum1 = 0.0;
float fNum2 = 0.0;
float fAns = 0.0;
int iOption = 0;



int main(void)
{
/* Set up the screen */
iScreenSetup();
/* Prompt the user and capture the data */
iDataCapture();
/* Process the data */
iProcessData();
/* Generate the report */
iReport();
/* Exit routine */
iExit();
} /* End of main */
```

Comment: You haven't specified the return type in the function declaration. By default it will take `int`. Eg. `iScreenSetup();` should be `<datatype> iScreenSetup();` for example `int iScreenSetup();`.

Comment: This has to do with [implicit int](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26488502/1708801), in C89 if you do not specify a type is defaults to `int`, although after C99 this was gone [many compiler still support it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26529235/1708801).

Comment: As you function name starts from `i`, it should return `int`. Eg. `int iScreenSetup();`

Comment: I'm hit with an error 'undefined reference to textcolor' any tips?

Comment: Some C's come with "conio.h", which is not standard, and most of these contain a textcolor() function, but probably not all. If that is a problem, post a new question and show the code that actually uses textcolor.

Answer (score 7):

Your prototypes are missing a return type. If nothing is to be returned, that would be `void`.

```
/* Prototypes */
void iScreenSetup();
```

Comment: Thanks a million! I was wrecking my brain trying to figure it out.

Comment: @Fiery-Skyline: Note, that this is still not a prototype declaration (as the comment suggests), but an (obsolescent) old-style declaration. A protoype would be for example `void iScreenSetup(void)`. With the old-style version (among other problems), your compiler probably doesn't tell you when you call it with the wrong number of arguments (or with arguments of wrong type).