# Why it is allowed to declare a C function no return type specfied?

Tags: c, function

I was surprised to find that this is a valid function declaration in C:

```
f() {
    return 10; 
}
```

The return type of the function is not specified. It not only compiles, but it actually returns 10.

```
void main() {
        int i = f();
        printf("i = %d\n", i); 
}
```

This code results in the following output:

```
i = 10
```

This is compiled with gcc 4.8.4.
Why function declaration with no return type explicitly specified compiles without errors/warnings?

**EDIT**: As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290038/is-the-return-type-part-of-the-function-signature) the return type is not part of the function signature and you can not overload functions based on different return types, but that does not answer the question is return type required for function declaration.

Comment: C used to allow for implicit int return type

Comment: Because of support for [implicit int](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26529235/1708801) to prevent breaking old code even though C99 dropped it.

Comment: Please change `void main()` to `int main()`. You don't return a value, but `main()` is the only function where the compiler will `return 0` for you.

Comment: It is valid in pre-standard C and C89/90.  It is not valid in the old standard (C99) or the current standard (C11).  Compilers continue to support it for reasons of backwards compatibility, but [GCC 5.1.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html) has moved to make the default compilation mode C11 with GNU extensions (`-std=gnu11`) instead of C90, so definitions such as `f` will generate at least warnings by default.

Comment: For a discussion of the `main()` function (in extenso), see [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ANSI C (C89/90), an unspecified return type is implicitly `int`. This has been officially disallowed since C99, but that doesn't stop compilers from implementing it. If compiling in C99 or C11 mode, GCC's `-pedantic` or a similar flag ought to issue a warning for it.

EDIT: In GCC 4.9, `-Wall` warns for it in default (GNU C) mode, and `-pedantic` warns for it with `-std=c99`.

Comment: The term "ANSI C" is commonly, *but incorrectly*, used to refer to the language defined by the 1989 standard. ANSI (the American National Standards Institute) has adopted each version of the ISO C standard as it's been published; it currently recognizes C11, and only C11. I suggest "ISO C90" instead.

Comment: C89 was the ANSI standard; ISO C90 was the general standard that replaced C89 shortly afterwards even in the USA.  The GCC `-ansi` flag means `-std=c89` (aka `-std=c90`).

Comment: I'll admit it is ambiguous, but *incorrect* is definitely subjective; the term "ANSI C" is used everywhere from Wikipedia to compiler docs to refer to C89/C90. Given that the ANSI has never referred to the language as anything more than "C" or otherwise distinguished their later standards from those of the ISO, it might be more incorrect to say that "ANSI C" properly refers to the latest-ratified standard when existing documentation uses it almost exclusively to refer to the original 1989 ANSI and 1990 ISO standards.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a valid function declaration in *modern* C (it was in the "classic" C89/90 version of the language). The fact that your compiler accepts it does not mean it is valid. It simply means that your compiler is not configured to strictly enforce the modern requirements of standard C language.

The latter is also evident in the fact that it permitted you to declare `main` with `void` return type.

If you want to use GCC for the purposes of verifying formal validity of the code, you need to specify `-std=...` and `-pedantic-errors` switches in the command line. It won't make it foolproof, but it will make it much more compliant.

P.S. By default GCC will let you do this even in C++ code. And it has never been legal in C++.

Comment: Defining `void main()` is not a constraint violation; no diagnostic is required. But it has undefined behavior *unless* the implementation documents it as a permitted form. **Don't do that.**

Comment: And as a consequence, GCC is within its rights to complain about `void main()` because it doesn't document it as a permitted form.

Answer (score 0):

Both the function declarations of `f` and `main` are not C compliant. A modern C compiler shall issue a diagnostic message.

Earlier, before adopting the C99 Standard, if the function return type is not specified then it is assumed that it is `int`.

Some compilers, as for example MS VC++, allow to declare function main as having return type `void`; however, according to the C Standard (and C++ Standard) function main shall have return type `int`.

In C function main shall be declared like (if it does not have parameters)

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: Note that C does allow 'or in some other implementation-defined manner' (C++ does not, but can hardly prevent the implementation doing it anyway), and the MS implementation appears to define `void main()` as an implementation-defined manner.  See [What should `main()` return in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/) for the details.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler "Inplementation-defined manner" is relative only to the number and types of the function parameters. All implementation-defined declaratopns of main shall have return type int.

Comment: That's not what the plain English of the standard says.  To quote: **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**

_The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no parameters:

`int main(void) { /* ... */ }`

or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be
used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):

`int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }`

 or equivalent;10) or in some other implementation-defined manner._

Comment: The semicolon before the 'or in some other implementation-defined manner' indicates that this alternative manner is unfettered by what has gone before.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  I think that you can not place other semicolons in this statement because if to place them then they have to be after the examples of the function declarations. It does not mean that an implementation-defined main may have some other return type except int.

Comment: Also, **5.1.2.2.3 Program termination** starts _If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`, …  If the return type is not compatible with `int`, …_  This clearly indicates that the standard permits return types other than `int`, but they are covered (only allowed) under the 'or in some other implementation-defined manner' clause.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  Compare this paragraph in C with the corresponding paragraph in C++: "It shall have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined."

Comment: What the C++ standard says is not germane to this question which is tagged solely with C.  You're correct; the C++ standard _is_ different and _is_ more restrictive than C.  You can't call `main` in C++; you can in C.  Etc.  I've already cross-referenced the question where the answers (especially [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/18721336#18721336)) spell this out in detail, including the contrast between C and C++.

Comment: @@Jonathan Leffler In my opinion the phrase in 5.1.2.2.3 does not mean that another return type is allowed. It simply states what can occur in this case if the function return type is not compatible with int.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler   Well, try to read the beginning "The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int"  as a single phrase. Pay attention to the verb shall.

Comment: It can't declare a prototype for the function because C doesn't support overloading and there's no way to write a single prototype that allows both the documented forms. (It can't use ellipsis `…`; there must be a named argument before it, which rules out the `int main(void)` notation.) Reading two independent sentences as one is also incorrect; they are separate. I disagree with the way you are trying to construe it (the standard would say nothing about what happens with other return types for `main` if it was not allowed under any circumstances), but I'm not going to continue the discussion.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Well,what about this  J.1 Unspecified behavior: "— The termination status returned to the hosted environment if the return type of main is not compatible with int (5.1.2.2.3)."?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82864/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Answer (score 0):

every function has an default return type as integer  according to ANSI C.This is the reason why this does not give error (return not specified).

```
int f() {
        printf("hmm\n"); 
}



f() {
    return 10.1; 
}
```

output will either be 10 or it will give an error depends......