# C function working without specifying data type of the argument

Tags: c, mpi

By mistake I used the following function in MPI -

```
double f(x) {
  return(4.0/(1 + x*x));
}
```

Notice that I have not declared the data type of `x` in the above code.

And then compiled it using :

```
mpicc q.c -o q
```

Still the program does not throw an error and compiles successfully.

And on using a wrapper, I get the following values of `f` -

f(2) = 0.8

f(1) = 2

**How is this working without an error?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189962/implicit-int-in-c-language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In old style C any declared with name but without type variable has a type of `int`. So fuction will take integer argument, and in expression it will be promoted to double.

UPDATE

In the pre-standard version of C and in the first standardized version C89 variable declared without type was of type `int` by default. Such behavior was removed in C99 and consecutive standards. One can read about it in the Kernigan&Ritchie book [`C Programming Language, 2nd Edition`](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628).

Comment: Oh. That's interesting. I did not know that. Is there a source where I can read this stuff up?

Comment: @97amarnathk It was in pre-standard and in first standard of C language - C89 (adopted in 1989 as you could surmise). It was removed in all consecutive C standards. I read it in the famous C book from K&R: https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-2nd-Brian-Kernighan/dp/0131103628

Comment: Oh nice. Will read that. I am accepting your answer :). Also it would be helpful if you add this link in the answer itself. Thanks.

Comment: @97amarnathk Done

Comment: That's not quite correct. An undeclared variable was an error. A old-style function declaration let you declare the name, but not the type, of a parameter; the type would default to `int`. In C99 and later, old-style function declarations are still permitted, but you must declare the type; the "implicit `int`" rule was dropped.

Answer (score 2):

```
double f(x) {
  return(4.0/(1 + x*x));
}
```

This compiles because (a) C still permits some old features that are considered obsolescent, and (b) you're not asking your compiler to enforce the current version of the language.

In modern C, a function should be declared/defined with a *prototype*, a declaration that specifies the types of any parameters:

```
double f(int x) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Pre-ANSI C (prior to 1989) didn't support prototypes, and function parameters were defined with a different syntax.  For example, you could write:

```
double f(x)
int x;
{
    /* ... */
}
```

The type of the parameter was not visible to callers, so calling `f` with an argument of a type other than `int` could have unpredictable results. (This was obviously a problem, which is why prototypes were introduced.) Furthermore, you could omit the `int x;` line and the type would default to `int`. And you could omit the `double` return type and that would also default to `int`.

Old-style declarations are still permitted, but it's rarely a good idea to use them. The implicit `int` rule was dropped in the 1999 standard.

You should find out how to ask your compiler to enforce the rules of modern C. If you're using gcc, then `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic` is a good start.